# Automatic kernel security updates no long being installed

Tags: kernel, security

A while back my `/boot` partition filled up on my Ubuntu server 14.04 install. This caused an automatic kernel security update to fail and be in a partially installed state. To fix the problem I removed the kernel that was partially installed, then ran `apt-get autoremove` to clear out the boot partition. At that point I thought everything was working properly.

Just recently I noticed, however, that the kernel version on this box is different from my other server 14.04 install. This other machine never had the problems with the boot partition, which is why I think that is what is causing the problem.

So the machine that had the boot partition issue is at 3.13.0-68-generic while the machine that has not had the boot partition issue is at 3.13.0-76-generic.

How do I get the machine to resume auto-installing kernel security updates?

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy linux-generic`

```
apt-cache policy linux-generic
linux-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.13.0.76.82
  Version table:
     3.13.0.76.82 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.13.0.24.28 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy linux-generic` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 updated with the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `linux-generic` package is not installed for some reason. That's why you do not get kernel updates.

You can install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Comment: It is interesting. I have a few different server VMs. Some of them have `linux-generic` installed and some don't. All of them receive the automatic kernel security updates except the one.

Comment: Other servers may have `linux-generic-lts-xxxx` packages, etc. Or they may have `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic`.